# client ip behind nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm running an nginx reverse proxy to be able to run multiple servers behind my firewall. I noticed on my mail server the error log is filled with "failed login from < local ip of nginx >" and I was wondering how can I set it so I get the remote IP of the person/bot that is trying to login so I might use that information for auto blocking those addresses (for example)?

This is my current config:

```
server {
    listen 8443 ssl http2;
    server_name mail.domain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass https://<internal ip>/;
        client_max_body_size 0;
        proxy_connect_timeout 3600;
        proxy_send_timeout 3600;
        proxy_read_timeout 3600;
        send_timeout 3600;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for one of these

```
proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

you can add these to http, server or location block and read the header in your app to filter the request

Comment: I believe I have already tried these, but gave the same results. Should I make changes to my mailserver too?

Comment: @vespino the logic for reading the IP and blocking the request has to be on your mail server itself. If you want to block all requests and allow only from specific IPs you can use something like 

location / {

allow 1.2.3.4;

deny all; }

Comment: I understand the blocking part having be done on the mailserver since that is where the logs are, but if I added the rules correctly, I still got my local ip in the log files and not the external ip.

Comment: Tried again just to be sure, but these lines result in the same, so the local ip being shown instead of the remote/external ip.

Comment: @vespino nginx has some default logging, can you check access_log file to see if you can find the remote IP there?

Comment: that log only shows 127.0.0.1 for all requests.

Comment: that's super weird cuz for me it only shows remote IP addresses, maybe you're having some other issue with the server while logging in? Don't you see any failed requests on the client?

Comment: Apparently it's a thing in the server and people have complained about this, but Kerio never did solve it: https://forums.kerio.com/index.php?t=msg&th=38074

Answer (score 0):

Just found out my mail server (Kerio) does nothing with the information forwarded by the reverse proxy, so the only thing I can do is hope for an update that does.